# Content being pushed down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We have a group of avatars held in a container, I want to add a plus symbol at the end of the group so that the user can select to add more people,

When I add it the new component is forced down. I can;t see how to stop this happening.

[image]

working code pen

https://codepen.io/jachno/pen/zYOLbyd

```css
.avatar {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar span {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar+.avatar-content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.avatar-lg {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.avatar-sm {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.avatar-group .avatar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.avatar-group .avatar:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.avatar-group .avatar+.avatar {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:10px">

  <div class="avatar-group">
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" v-tooltip="'Ryan Tompson'" data-original-title="steve Hadid">
      <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid" v-tooltip="'Romina Hadid'"> <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/48.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign `.avatar-group{display:flex}` in order to make it work

```css
.avatar {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar span {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar+.avatar-content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.avatar-lg {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.avatar-sm {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.avatar-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.avatar-group .avatar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.avatar-group .avatar:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.avatar-group .avatar+.avatar {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:10px">

  <div class="avatar-group">
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" v-tooltip="'Ryan Tompson'" data-original-title="steve Hadid">
      <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid" v-tooltip="'Romina Hadid'"> <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/48.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add CSS `vertical-align:top` to tag `a` having class `avatar-sm`  in order to make it work

```css
.avatar {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar span {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar+.avatar-content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.avatar-lg {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.avatar-sm {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.avatar-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.avatar-group .avatar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.avatar-group .avatar:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.avatar-group .avatar+.avatar {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div style="padding:10px">

  <div class="avatar-group">
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" v-tooltip="'Ryan Tompson'" data-original-title="steve Hadid">
      <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid" v-tooltip="'Romina Hadid'"> <img alt="Image placeholder" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/48.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```